# How can I list all the categories under a Custom Post Type (taxonomy)?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

So I have created a custom post type and under that taxonomy named "Category" which serves for categories. How can I list all the categories from there?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to list them you can use the get_terms function:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';

 }
 echo '</ul>';
}
```

Read the codex, it has a lot of examples:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Answer (score 1):

nm I should start my own question...

EDIT: I figured out what I was going to ask, but if anybody stumbles on this original question, here's what you can also do to just link to the categories after they are listed:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'nameofyourregisteredtaxonomygoeshere' );
$count = count( $terms );
if ( $count > 0 ) {
echo '<h3>Total Projects: '. $count . '</h3>';
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" alt="'. esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    echo '</li>';


}
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```